# Replace syntax brackets by visible brackets

Tags: bibtex, verbatim, brackets

##### General overview

I have a BibTeX entry of the document I am working on itself, and I put this deffinition in a variable to be able to use it everywhere I whant. The goal is to print on the document this entry (in order to give the reader a way to cite this document in their own BibTeX works).

##### The problem

But, as the BibTeX contain brackets, when I call the function, the brackets are interpreted as LaTeX syntax, so they desapear.

##### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\title{foo}
\author{baz}
\date{Bar}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\bibtexselfentry{
 @book{thisDocumentItself,

    title  = {\@title},

    author = {\@author},

    publisher = {Éditeur},

    year = {\@date}
 }
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\bibtexselfentryVisible{%
  \StrSubstitute{\bibtexselfentry}{\{}{\textbraceleft}[\temp]%
  \StrSubstitute{\temp}{\}}{\textbraceright}%
  \temp
}

\begin{document}

Cite this work with the following Bib\TeX{} definition:

\texttt{\bibtexselfentry}

\end{document}
```

##### Output rendering

[image: Rendering]

As you see, the brackets totaly desapear.

##### The solution I imagine

As you see in my MWE, I add a `\bibtexselfentryVisible` command to substitute syntax brackets by visible brackets, but it have pretty no effect on the final behaviour.

##### The question

How to make the brackets of `\bibtexselfentry` visible when I need it?
It should not be always visible, because sometimes `\bibtexselfentry` could act like a real BibTeX command.

Comment: It might be a little easier to save your BibTeX entries into one or more files, and load them with `\verbatiminput{my_file.bib}` from the [`verbatim`](https://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim) package.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to copy-paste BibTeX entries into your main document, rather than saving them into separate files, you could use `\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{my_file.bib}` and `\end{filecontents}`.

Comment: @gz839918 it would be very hard. Because as you see, some bibTeX values are not hardwriten but depend from some variables, like `\@title`. So if I use `\verbatimimput` I’ll get litteraly “\@title” instead of the real title.

Comment: Is "this document itself" the sole citation you want to print? If not, how many other citations do you need? If it's a small number, it may be possible to accomplish manually.

Comment: You will need an instructional version to go into your help manual ( @book\{thisDocumentItself,
    title  = \{\@title\},
    author = \{\@author\},
    publisher = \{Éditeur\},
    year = \{\@date\}
 \}) and a real version. Use \ escape character. `{\@title}` cannot be half-text `{` `}` and half command at the same time.

Comment: I would use `\{` and `\}` and when you come to writ ethis to a file for actual use locally redefine those so they write as `{` and `}` so the bib file is working